# Cin Array Moved into a Function Error C++

Tags: c++

** Note this isn't anything that's due I already turned in the assignment I'm just learning how to send arrays to functions **

So the problem is when I go to compile it gives me an error code stating that it cannot convert a "double*" to a "double" which doesn't make sense to me as I have made sure the filetypes are correct and I believe I'm following the instructions handed to me to a letter. I've read I can add a * to sales (sales*) but then it needs a primary-expression beforehand and that method isn't something we've been taught.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;




void printArray (double, int);
int main()

{

int selects;
string candy[selects]= {"Cadbury Eggs", "Lollipops", "Chocolate Bunnies", "Peeps", "Jellybeans"};
 double sales [selects];

double totalSales;


printArray (sales,5);


for (int i=0; i<5; i++)

{ cout<< "The total sales for "<< candy[i]<< ": "<< sales[i] <<endl;}



return 0;


}




void printArray (double array [], int size)

{
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++)


  {int selects;   
  string candy[selects]= {"Cadbury Eggs", "Lollipops", "Chocolate Bunnies", "Peeps", "Jellybeans"};  

  cout<< "What are the sales for "<< candy[i]<<endl;
  cin>>array[i];

  if (array[i]<0)
 {cout<< "Thats an invalid input try again "<<endl;
    cin>>array[i];}}

  }
```

Comment: Since this is C++ you should be using `std::vector` as a standard "array container" instead of slinging C-style arrays which require both pointer + length to be sent in tandem. Try and get into the habit of using `const std::vector<double>&` in preference to `double[]` as references are generally less messy than pointers.

Comment: Your declaration and definition don't match.

Comment: If this is yet another one of those C++ courses that completely fails to teach C++ and instead espouses some bizarre form of *fancy C* that's an invention of your educator that nobody else uses, sorry to hear that. In that case check that your function signature matches how you're calling it, and vice-versa. Easy fix, declare `printArray` in full before `main()` to avoid duplicate and contradictory definitions.

Comment: `int selects;   
  string candy[selects] = ...` what do you think will happen there? 1) you are trying to create a VLA which is non-standard. 2) `selects` is uninitialized so you have undefined behavior.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you "turned in the assignment" already. As others have pointed out, it suffers from multiple fatal flaws and bugs. You should expect to get very little credit for it, if any at all. Especially since, as I understand your explanation, you turned in something that doesn't even compile.

Comment: That is because an array is actually just a pointer, so your `printArray()` method needs to accept a pointer, not a `double`, it should be `double*`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I turned in the assignment without using functions and did good I'm just working on making 2d arrays and functions atm